# Magicsuggest - Turn off suggestion matching/filtering

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, magicsuggest

I'm using a jQuery plugin named [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html). It works fine but I have a special case. I want to turn off its suggestion matching feature. With its default feature, when I type 'New', it will suggest all the words with 'New' in it, but I want to display all suggestions regardless of what the users typed.

Is there a way to do that, and if so, how?

Comment: Fine, Let me know do you want to enable that input field or not ? Do we need to allow user to type for suggestions ? if we show all suggestions regardless of user input  then why we need to enable that input field ? Just make editable false and enable toggleOnclick. If you give me more info i will try to hack around it .

Comment: Ah its been almost 3 months since I asked this question. To be honest, I forgot whats my problem back then. As I remember, the client requested a feature change so I stopped looking for this solution

Comment: Should I delete this question? or are you willing to provide an answer for others?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show all suggestions regardless of user input then why should we enable that input box.

You can just disable input field using `editable : false, allowFreeEntries : false` and set `toggleOnClick: true` .

So that if you click on input field all suggestions will be appear and it wont allows you to type for suggestions.

Correct me if am wrong.